# Spin wheel control in Android

Tags: android

I need a control where user can pick a number from a list like one in below image.
This image is from myTouch 3g Slide. If this is part of android source, can somebody provide me the link?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that widget is available.

You can check "[The wheel widget for Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)" which does something similar.

Comment: Thank you, Let me take a look

Answer (score 3):

I have put up my code for a smoothly animated wheel here:

http://code.google.com/p/smooth-wheel/