# Eclipse import files into project

Tags: eclipse

This is for an Android project.

In the question [Spin wheel control in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090534/spin-wheel-control-in-android), I found 
this link http://code.google.com/p/smooth-wheel/.

I would like to add just the java (component) files to my project with a different directory 
in the source path. But smooth-wheel source has its own R.....

So the question is, How to add the java files and the R. file to my projects? so that R files
of smooth-wheel will be added to MY R. file?

In DELPHI it is easy to add component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, smooth-wheel has a .jar, that you can add to `libs/`. The R will be autogenerated, and you will have two different Rs, in different namespaces (technically you already have two, your.package.R and android.R)

**EDIT:** If there is no .jar, just copy/merge the files from `src/` and `res/`, don't worry about R, it is autogenerated. Though it looks pretty amateurish from "smooth-wheel" to release with the stock icon and no .jar

Comment: smooth-wheel has no jar it is a whole project by it self